# Access a method in custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView and a custom adapter. I want to change a variable in MyListAdapter object.
This is some code from my custom list Adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Something> {
    ........
    ........
    private int myPosition= -1;
    ........

    public void setMyPosition(int pos) {
        myPosition = pos;
    }
................
}
```

now in my Activity:

```
MyListAdapter<Something> listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item_transaction, accounts);

listAdapter.setMyPosition(2);
```

But I cannot access **setMyPosition** method.
In Eclipse I get *The method setMyPosition() is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter*

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare listAdapter to be of type MyListAdapter.  Otherwise it doesn't exist, Java can't call a function of a subclass if it doesn't exist on the parent.

This will only work if TransListAdapter is a subclass or MyListAdapter.  Otherwise the setMyPosition function won't exist there either.

Comment: Clean and build. If you object is of type MyListAdapter, it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class MyListAdapter<Something> extends ArrayAdapter<Something> {
    ........
    ........
    private int myPosition= -1;
    ........

    public void setMyPosition(int pos) {
        myPosition = pos;
    }
    ........
}
```

Comment: Still get: The method setPositionDetails() is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter

Comment: have you tried to add the <Something> after the class name in the declaration?

Comment: Yes I tried your solution but I receive a lot of other errors.
*Gabe Sechan* answer fixed it.